# how to access docker0 ip address remotely from centos host to windows machine

Tags: docker

A docker0 ip address is running a php code on nginx server in docker installed in centos 7 minimal. How can I access it remotely from windows 7 host machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While people were rather worried about formatting, I found the answer. :) It's as simple as to exposing the right port to the docker container.

```
#docker run -d --name continer-name -p server-ip-address:80:80 image-id
```

I just followed the above docker code & it worked like a charm! Hope it helps those who are stuck with a similar situation.